# cent OS ImportError: libedgetpu.so.1: cannot open shared object file

Tags: python

(

```
base) [aid_lab_centos@localhost TPU-Posenet]$ python3 pose_camera_single_tpu.py --videofile video1.mp4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pose_camera_single_tpu.py", line 7, in <module>
    from edgetpu.basic import edgetpu_utils
  File "/home/aid_lab_centos/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/edgetpu/__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    import edgetpu.basic.edgetpu_utils as utils
  File "/home/aid_lab_centos/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/edgetpu/basic/edgetpu_utils.py", line 15, in <module>
    import edgetpu.swig.edgetpu_cpp_wrapper as wrapper
  File "/home/aid_lab_centos/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/edgetpu/swig/edgetpu_cpp_wrapper.py", line 28, in <module>
    _edgetpu_cpp_wrapper = swig_import_helper()
  File "/home/aid_lab_centos/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/edgetpu/swig/edgetpu_cpp_wrapper.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_edgetpu_cpp_wrapper', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/home/aid_lab_centos/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/home/aid_lab_centos/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: libedgetpu.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

---

I think I can read the file without error code by setting the path in /etc/profile. help from people with post-net and deep learning in cent os.

Assuming the cord is working properly,
I want is that through this code, the result value must come out without object detection and frame loss in the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should install the libjasper library. run the following:
`sudo apt-get install libjasper-dev`